# "UIKeyboardWillShowNotification" cannot be received on iPad mini

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter, ipad-mini

I added following code to `viewWillAppear:animated` in main view controller.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(showKeyboard:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
```

And, I implemented this method in same class,

```
- (void)showKeyboard:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Keyboard will appear." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Main view controller has a UITextField object.

In iPad2 (iOS 5.0), an alert view appears when it was focused.
However, in iPad mini (iOS 6.0), nothing appears except a software keyboard.

I want to make iPad mini be same behavior as iPad2.

Thanks,

Comment: is "viewWillAppeaer:animated" how you spelled it in the code?

Comment: Oh..., it is a mere spelling mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of iOS 3.2, `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` are no longer fired when switching between two text fields. Basically, the notifications only fire if the keyboard is actually shown or hidden.  Use `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` instead.

```
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 3.2) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                                 selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) 
                                                     name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification 
                                                   object:nil];     
    } else {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                                 selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) 
                                                     name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification 
                                                   object:nil];
```

Comment: I tried to use `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` instead of that.
Unfortunately, the alteration had no effect on iPad mini...

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: **AHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH!!**

I AM SORRY...


I forgot that I had turned on `Split keyboard` option.